# Are questions seeking the perspective of a certain subset of Christians on the experiences of another group (Christian or otherwise) on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

My recently asked question [What is an overview of how Christians make sense of the testimonial evidence for alien abductions, alien close encounters & UFO sightings?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/84641/50422) seeking an overview of Christian viewpoints on the alien abduction & UFO phenomenon just got closed as off-topic. However, I have previously asked three on-topic questions following a more or less similar pattern:

- [Why do non-LDS Christians accept the testimonies of the apostles but reject the testimonies of the 3 & 8 witnesses to the golden plates?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/84581/50422), which seeks non-LDS views on the LDS witnesses to the golden plates.
- [Why do Cessationists consider recent testimonial evidence for the gifts of the Spirit less reliable than 2000-year-old evidence for the resurrection?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/83141/50422), which seeks Cessationist views on the testimonial evidence for Continuanionism.
- [How do Christians make sense of exorcisms in other religions?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/82539/50422), which seeks the Christian perspective on the (anecdotal) evidence of exorcisms in other religions.

The recently closed question and the three on-topic questions above have in common that they all seek the perspective of some subset of Christians on the reported experiences of another group. So why is it that the closed question is off-topic but the other three are on-topic? More generally, what conditions should be met by questions seeking the perspective of a certain subset of Christians on the experiences of another group (Christian or otherwise) in order to be regarded as on-topic?

---

Edit: following @curiosdannii's advice, I asked a (hopefully on-topic) improved version of the question: [What is an overview of Christian views on alien appearances and abductions?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/84668/50422)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had asked "What is an overview of Christian views on alien appearances and abductions?" I don't think anyone would have had an issue with your question.

The flaw in your question is that instead of asking that, you're asking for Christian *responses* to specific *testimonies or anecdotes*. Here's your answer: Some Christians would wholeheartedly believe such testimonies. Some would be sceptical. Some would snigger or even laugh. Some wouldn't even listen. Some would say that aliens are real and so are these experiences. Some would say they're made up. Some would say they come from psychological illnesses, or sleep deprivation. Some would say they're demonic.

Please, try to move away from asking about anecdotes, either asking for anecdotes, or asking about responses to them. There are billions of Christians giving anecdotes and billions responding to them. Occasional questions on anecdotes are fine, I've asked [at least one myself](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/78911/6071). But it shouldn't be your primary method of investigation, and it's not the focus of this site. Whenever you ask "Have any Christians claimed to experience X?" the answer is almost always yes. Whenever you ask how Christians respond to such claims, the answer will be like I gave you in the previous paragraph. In neither do we actually learn anything very useful. So instead, we focus here on doctrine and practice. So ask for an overview of Christian positions on the existence of aliens (if it hasn't been asked already). Ask about the doctrine of inspiration, or how various denominations weigh claims of prophetic revelation against the inspired scriptural revelation.

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb:

If you can't conceive of a person being able to come up one one stellar and concise answer to your question (as opposed to a bunch of fluff), don't ask the question.

Comment: How do you know questions about the alien abduction & UFO phenomenon can **only** be answered with *a bunch of fluff*?

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator An 'Investigator' will not have the same instincts as a Participator. Thus many questions can be instinctively answered (by a Participator) but an Investigator will have to (laboriously) plod through much 'fluff' (fluff in/fluff out as the saying goes) in order to eliminate every possible contingency imaginable. But one can only stand back in amazement as they do so, for it is a monumental task, indeed.